# functions having different speed in java

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, sleep, filenotfoundexception

In my program I have something like that: two functions in the same thread

```
function1();
function2();
```

Function1 uses a process builder to execute some commands and then writes the results in 3 different files.

Function2 reads the files and uses their data to continue the program.

The problem is that apparently function1 takes too much time that function2 often does not find the files created by function1.
Maybe the process runs the second function before function1 ends its processing.

Is there a way to solve this?
I thought about a thread.sleep

```
try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);                 
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
```

The problem with this is that the program became too slowly especially that I am working on an important amount of data.

Comment: are they called in different thread ? then use `join();` to wait for a thread to finish

Comment: Without more information and *real* code, it will be hard to understand what's wrong, and hard to give but very broad suggestions.

Comment: If it doesn't make sense to call `function2()` before `function1()` returns, then why not call them both from the same thread?

Comment: Actually I am calling them from the same thread. Still I have that error

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use waitFor() method until your process terminates in the function1() and then call function2().

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder(<process>).start();
p.waitFor();
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was the exact solution, but after all it made my program incredibly slow :/

Comment: Does your process, if you run that directly take same amount of time as java takes to complete function1()? If so, you should look for optimizing the process.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code: (input is an hashmap)

```
for (String fileName : input.get(project)) {
            fileInformation[0] = projectName;
            fileInformation[1] = fileName;
            runCommands(nameParameter, fileName);
            // try {
            // Thread.sleep(2000); // 1000 milliseconds is one second.
            // } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            // Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            // }
            ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> allPathsAndDatesResults = allPathsAndDates(nameParameter, fileName);
```

function 1 is here runCommands

```
public static void runCommands(String nameParameter, String fileName) throws InterruptedException {
    String batPath = Tool.getBatPath();
    List<String> cmdAndArgs = Arrays.asList(batPath);
    String dirPath = Tool.getShellDir() + nameParameter;
    File dir = new File(dirPath);
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmdAndArgs);
    pb.environment().put("fileName", fileName);
    pb.directory(dir);
    File log = new File("log");
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.appendTo(log));
    Process p;
    try {
        p = pb.start();
        assert pb.redirectInput() == Redirect.PIPE;
        assert pb.redirectOutput().file() == log;
        assert p.getInputStream().read() == -1;
        //p.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And function 2 is allPathsAndDates

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> allPathsAndDates(String nameParameter, String fileName)
        throws IOException {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> allFiles = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    String allPaths = Tool.getResultsPath() + "\\" + fileName + "_Path.txt";
    String allDates = Tool.getResultsPath() + "\\" + fileName + "_Date.txt";

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(allPaths)); //etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call `function1()` then `function2()`, you won't have a problem. Don't use threads if the operations don't have to be done simultaneously.

If you have to use threads, as said Jiga Joshi in the comments, you can use the `join()` function to force a thread to wait for another thread's execution end.

Comment: I am not using threads actually, I am only calling function1 then function2, but still I have that problem.
The first time a launch the program, function2 doesn't find the files, when I re run the program again, then function2 finds the files and continue its execution